# Query to Find max of three columns in a row

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have three dates in table, for each record i need to find out max of three columns and need to ignore incase if the column is null, could you please help on this ?

I am using oracle 10g version.

```
Table-1
---------
SL NO date1 date2 date3 age
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `GREATEST` will return `NULL` if any of the values that you pass it is `NULL`, you need a combination of `GREATEST` and `COALESCE`:

```
SELECT GREATEST(
    COALESCE(date1, date2, date3)
,   COALESCE(date2, date1, date3)
,   COALESCE(date3, date1, date2)
)
FROM my_test_table
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `GREATEST` function, which returns the largest of the given n arguments:

```
SELECT GREATEST(date1, date2, date3)
FROM   table1
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly (your post is not very clear), you can use the `GREATEST` function:

```
sslect
...,
GREATEST (date1,date2,date3)
from...
```